# Scheme - standard way in R5RS to execute an external command?

Tags: scheme, r5rs

Is there a way in Scheme Revision 5 to call out to an external program? For example:

```
(system "ls")
```

If not, is there any "official" way to do this, such as specified in a SRFI or a later revision of the Scheme spec (R6RS, etc)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

(It's generally a bad idea to try to write code with "Standard Scheme", and `system` is one of those things that is unlikely to become standard enough to be usable outside of a particular implementation or via some compatibility library.)

Comment: Good to know - thanks for the answer. I am curious though - why exactly is writing "standard scheme" a bad idea? Is it because individual implementations provide so much in term of their own libraries, packages, etc?

Comment: It because the standard is thin enough to inherently not include stuff that specific implementations will always have.  It's basically why "Scheme" is better thought of as family of similar languages rather than a specific language.  (The specific language view works as long as you stay out of such "real work").

Comment: I write a lot of code in standard scheme (R5RS) and use popular SRFIs (1,9). So what do you mean by "bad idea"?

Comment: I meant "for real work" -- anything that requires running subprocesses (as in this case), guis, network connections, concurrency, databases, etc etc.

Comment: OK - I'm not trying to start a flame war or anything. Just trying to understand the Scheme specifications and how they fit into day-to-day programming...